# Calculate modulo of a large number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

first post here, can I get some help?

I need to calculate $      2^{457}\mod2539$ without calculator or anything and it is driving me nuts.

Comment: I was searching shortcuts too, but found none, and frankly squaring these $4$ digits numbers manually and then perform the division by $2539$ is tedious. I hoped for $2^a\equiv 1\pmod {2539}$ with $a\mid 2538$ but no miracle smallest $a=2538$.

Comment: This is certainly not something I would try "without calculator or anything".  Is this an actual question you were assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious short-cut.  It can be brute forced by computing successive squarings and take  $$2^{457}\equiv 2\cdot 2^{8} \cdot 2^{64}\cdot 2^{128} \cdot 2^{256} \equiv 1079 \mod{2539}$$  The real calculations start with 
$$\begin{align}
2^{16} &\equiv (256)^2 \equiv 2061 \mod{2539} \\ 
2^{32} &\equiv (2061)^2 \equiv 2513 \mod{2539} \\
2^{64} &\equiv (2513)^2 \equiv 676 \mod{2539} \\
2^{128} &\equiv (676)^2 \equiv 2495 \mod{2539} \\ 
2^{256} &\equiv (2495)^2 \equiv 1936 \mod{2539}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use the *fast exponentiation algorithm* mod.$2539$: for the exponent $457$, it requires $8$ squarings and $4$ multiplications. Here is how it goes:

**Input**: $a$, $n$.

**Output**: $P=a^n$.

**Initialisation**: $P\leftarrow 1$;

**While** $n>0$ **do**

**If** $n$ odd **then** $P\leftarrow a$ **endif**;

$\;n\leftarrow \lfloor n/2\rfloor$; $a\leftarrow a^2$;

**endwhile**;